# Who are the industry leaders in the QA/Test space?

Tags: manual-testing, qa-developer, interview

I've googled the question and come up with lists published by various companies but they always seem focused on those who are the most prevalent speakers, presenters or bloggers. Should I just assume they're the most prevalent for a reason or are there less outspoken leaders who have more insight and/or are working on really interesting problems?

Comment: Not sure what is your goal, what you want to accomplish. As you learn more, you can see how different people have different agenda and different approaches (which might be different from your own). It your goal not to waste time by reading "lesser" leaders?

Comment: @PeterMasiar, Good question. I'm, basically, interested in learning about functional and non-functional testing trends and future related to IoT/wearables from balanced, thoughtful, optimistic, leaders in the QA space beyond the default leaders we hear about most due to their social media volume. (aka I don't just want to hear the most opinionated QA personalities.)

Comment: Do you have any examples of people you aren't looking to hear from?  I don't know what group you're speaking about that you don't want to hear from (will help give suggestions on people to list).

Comment: I will add individual people anwsers for voting.

Comment: How voting in popularity contest will help to find out what OP's goal is? And why you think that best mind will even consider wasting time on forums like this? Being here (for me) is a proof that person does not have some real projects which can make real difference. No offense, I am here too because this is the best way I can help. One of the few "luminaries" with real name recognition I know who spends time on forums here is [Alex Martelli](http://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) and he has karma to prove it.

Comment: @PeterMasiar, I'm not looking to start a popularity contest or, on the contrary, a flame war. I know who the most "social" QA leaders are according to Facebook and Twitter and I simply wanted a fresh opinion. No hidden agenda, no goal other than getting a few new names, this is for my own edification and curiosity.

Comment: I do generally find that there is a strong correlation between the most prevalent speakers and presenters and those folks being proficient in their fields.  It's not 100% but most of the time I find that presenters know their subjective material fairly well in order to have the confidence to speak, present and take questions it.

Comment: mattsolar: Maybe you think your question is not a popularity contest (my comment was aimed more at @MichaelDurrant 's 3 answers) but can you suggest some **objective** criteria to measure thought leader qualities of different people? IOW, how you can measure that someone is only 0.7 size leader but someone else is 2.5?

Comment: @PeterMasiar, oh, don't get me wrong - it's highly subjective. :) As a rookie I just want to know who the QA-All-stars follow for educational purposes. :)

Comment: @mattsolar - Exactly. And questions for which only highly subjective answers are possible is good format for your own blog, but bad fit for any of the SO exchanges. That's why your question was closed. It is nothing personal. We just prefer that people with good karma earned it by providing high quality answers to valid questions, not just being opinionated. So good answers can bubble to the top, and at least one corner of the internet is a better place :-)

Answer (score 1):

I find that Lisa Crispin, who wrote Agile Testing Along with Janet Gregory is fantastic

Answer (score 0):

I've been impressed by https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/213/bj-rollison both in this community and when I've seen him present at conferences.

Answer (score 0):

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/246/user246 is clearly the leader in our space her in Stack Exchange.  Unfortunately they prefer to keep an air of mystery.